# Динамическое добавление срок таблицы по клику

Tags: javascript, django

Реализовал js метод, который должен вставлять кусок html кода в tbody для добавления новых строк. Скрипты подключил, однако "магии" не происходит. Прошу помочь разобраться, где я накосячил...

Подключаю свой js (строка в самом конце шаблона html, если это важно)

```
<script src="{% static 'custom/js/custom_js.js' %}"></script>
```

Кусок html целевой страницы

```
<table class="table table-borderless" id="ItemInRecipTable">
            <thead class="table-info">
                <tr>
                    <th>Ингридиенты</th>
                    <th>Количество (гр.)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="item-choice" class="form-control">
                            {% for item in items %}
                                <option value={{ item.id }}>{{ item.name }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="amount-item-1" class="form-control">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>

        <br>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="addrow" onclick="AddRow()" value="Добавить ингридиент" />
```

Вот код js

```
var i = 1;
function AddRow() {
  i++;
  $('#ItemInRecipTable').find('tbody').append('<tr><td><select name="item-choice" class="form-control">{% for item in items %}<option value={{ item.id }}>{{ item.name }}</option>{% endfor %}</select></td><td><input type="number" name="amount-item-'+ i +'" class="form-control"></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: Статический js-файл не является шаблоном, поэтому пытаться писать в нём что-то типа `{% for item in items %}` нет никакого смысла

Comment: Лучше на клиенте реализовать запрос к бэку, который вернет список строк и чистым js эти строки добавить.

Comment: @andreymal Мне казалось, что js просто вставит кусок html кода, который прописан в append, я не прав?

Comment: @SwaD имеется ввиду на клиенте ввести что-то типа "Сколько ингредиентов хотите добавить?". Допустим 10 и потом отобразить таблицу на 10 строк?
Возможная логика, но хотелось бы сделать нормально через добавление строк по кнопке, чтобы не снижать UE

Comment: UPD я попробовал в append просто прописать '<td>Добавил</td><td>Добавил</td>', но это все равно не сработало.

Comment: А вы jQuery подключили? И если не работает, то должны быть ошибки. А еще, что бы addRow отработало, фукнцию надо как то вызвать

Comment: @SwaD, нет jQuery я не подключал, так как не использую. Я подключил только свой js. 
А функцию AddRow я вызываю по клику кнопки onclick="AddRow()"

Comment: А, кнопку не заметил... `$('#ItemInRecipTable').find('tbody')` - это синтаксис jQuery. На чистом js это будет так: `document.getElementById('ItemInRecipTable').querySelector('.table-info')`. Ну и append просто так не сработает. Чистый js вам просто строку добавит, а что бы получился hTML элемент надо либо innerHTML использовать, либо отдельн создавать элемент `document.createElement('tr')` а потом его уже аппендить

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480492/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-div-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8), там есть 2 примера добавления данных чистым js

Comment: @SwaD, добавил jQuery. и логика добавления строки заработала корректно и строку я добавил. А вот теперь пошел читать про innerHTML, чтобы вставить именно HTML код, без которого не работают функции шаблонизатора. Я получаю просто {{ item.name }} без возможности выбора из объектов передаваемого класса.

И есть у меня тихое подозрение, что не заработают...

Comment: Забыл выразить благодарность! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Приведённый код в вопросе работает корректно, если подключить jQuery. Однако, это не позволяет обрабатывать корректно логику шаблонизатора.

Для этого необходимо:

1. релизовать логику REST API в Джанго (например, Django REST Framework (DRF))
2. Делать вызов этого REST API на стороне js, получать необходимые данные
3. Формировать строку html разметки и выводить.

По факту мы не используем шаблонизатор, но получаем нужный эффект.